# Cannot import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using a SUSE linux 64-bit distribution on a shared server.

I installed Anaconda python distribution locally. Unfortunately the following line returns an error in the python command line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The error states that pyqt4 module cannot be found. I took the following steps to ensure I have the PyQt framework:

```
conda install pyqt
```

Additionally, I also tried changing the backend by explicitly typing the following before importing:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4'] = 'PySide'
```

But I get the same error. I also found the version of the PyQt module installed to be v5.6. I am not sure how to get matplotlib.pyplot to be imported.

The python version I am using with anaconda is Python 2.7.12, which is installed in /home/username/.local/anaconda. There is another system python distribution (version 2.6.9) installed in /usr/bin/

Upon uninstalling the entire anaconda framework, I am able to get the matplotlib to work in the system version. I have uninstalled and re-installed anaconda multiple times. Every time, I encounter the same import error.

Any help would be wonderful! Please let me know if additional information is required. Many thanks!

Comment: Your title has typos in it.

Comment: @StrawMan This might be a long shot but try using `pip install`. I've found that it sometimes works better that `conda install`

Comment: @Neill Yes, I tried that too. Whenever I try to install PyQt, I essentially get the same message - that I  already have version 5.6 installed. Thanks!